# Laravel "custom" routes always resolves to 404

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm using laravel 5.7 when I encounter 404 error on my custom routes along with the `Route::resource` entries on the same `Route::group`.

**Format on web route**

```
Route::group
    Route::resource
    Route::get
```

**Symptoms:**

- Using `route('something.page.custom')` will resolve to expected URL.
- Unsolvable by:
  `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

This is not on the docs of Laravel 5.7 yet.

**From** resource first

```
Route::group
    Route::resource
    Route::get
```

**To** resource last

```
Route::group
    Route::resource
    Route::get
```

Seems like `resource` is cancelling the resolving for the custom routes.

**Other** solution:

If this won't work, disable the 404 exception catch and review the error stacks. But please let me know how to do that. :)